# Причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, прилагательные, причастия, удвоенные-буквы

Помогите правильно написать. Слитно или раздельно пишется с не и Н или НН: еще нехоженые дороги. Нехоженые-это прилагательное или причастие с зависимым словом? Спасибо/. И если нетрудно, можно ли изменить по падежам диван-кровать. Учительница моего ребенка утверждает, что это сложное слово и в нем изменяется только второе слово, в интернете пишут, что меняются обе части. Кому верить?

Answer (score 4):

1) Большой толковый словарь:

ДИВАН-КРОВАТЬ, дивана-кровати; м. Диван с откидной спинкой, используемый в качестве кровати. Диваны-кровати с матрасами на выбор.

2) **Еще нехоженые** ― прилагательное, образовано от **непереходного** глагола, поэтому не может быть страдательным причастием.

Пример: Во второй половине прошлого века, когда доступные земли Америки были почти полностью поделены, оставались земли в горах не только не застолбленные, но даже **еще нехоженые**. [Василий Песков, Борис Стрельников. Земля за океаном (1977)]

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3):

> И если нетрудно, можно ли изменить по падежам ***диван-кровать.***
>   Учительница моего ребенка утверждает, что это сложное слово и в нем
>   изменяется только второе слово, в интернете пишут, что меняются обе
>   части.

.

Неправы и учительница, отвергающая возможность склонения обеих частей в слове *диван-кровать*, и те люди в интернете,
что считают единственно верным вариант со склонением обеих частей.

Потому что **наиболее авторитетными словарями  считаются абсолютно правильными   оба варианта склонения.**

См. у *Еськовой ("Краткий словарь трудностей русского языка", М., 2005):*

> **диван-кровать**, диван**а**-кроват**и**, *мн.* диван**ы**-кроват**и**, диван**ов**-кроват**ей**, *м. и* **диван-кровать**, диван-кроват**и**, *мн.*
>   диван-кроват**и**,  диван-кроват**ей**, *ж.*
>
> *На новом диване-кровати. На новой диван-кровати.*

.

То же у *Аванесова ("Орфоэпический словарь русского языка", М., 1989)*...

То же и в *«Большом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка» М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткина, Р. Ф. Касаткиной (М., 2012)*...

То же  в ***["Русском орфографическом словаре"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)*** (Лопатин и др.)...

.

> Слитно или раздельно пишется с ***не*** и ***Н*** или ***НН:*** *еще
>   нехоженые дороги*. ***Нехоженые*** -- это прилагательное или причастие
>   с зависимым словом?

.

***Нехоженый*** -- прилагательное, пишущееся с одним ***н.*** Фиксируется многими словарями, в том числе и ***["Русским орфографическим словарём"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)*** (**со звёздочкой*, говорящей о возможности раздельного написания *не/хоженый* в определённых контекстах**).

Есть в *РОС* и прилагательное без ***не***: [***хоженый***.](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

.

А вот слитно или же раздельно писать *не/хоженые* в данном случае…

Я бы выбрал раздельное написание:

***…еще не хоженые дороги.***

Воспользуюсь аргументацией *Розенталя* и *Добромыслова*, приведённой ими когда-то в обоснование возможности и целесообразности раздельного написания частицы ***не*** в сочетании ***не/похожие на меня***:

> Хотя правило о раздельном написании частицы ***не*** с причастиями,
>   имеющими при себе зависимые слова, не распространяется на
>   прилагательные, последние могут писаться раздельно с частицей
>   ***не,*** если логически подчёркивается отрицание.

.

Пример из Гугл-книг:

*Искусство как путь общественного служения лежит обычно в стороне от большой дороги к славе; чувство нового ведет артиста всякий раз **еще не хожеными тропами** поиснов и ...*

===

И всё же… Пишу ***не хоженые*** с одним ***н***, а рука сама тянется написать с двумя…

В 2000 г.  издательство «У-Фактория»  выпустило составленный *Ю.В. Алабугиной* (по-моему, в соавторстве с *А.Н. Тихоновым*) *«Орфографический словарь для школьников»*.  С момента выхода этот словарь регулярно переиздаётся. Так вот в нём при раздельном написании с ***не*** — два ***н:***

> ***нехоженый*** и ***не хоженный***

И не только этот словарь рекомендует такое написание. Раздельное написание с двумя ***н*** рекомендует и *"Орфографический словарь русского языка" Б.З. Букчиной,  И.К.Сазоновой* и Л.К. *Чельцовой*, приказом Министерства образования и науки РФ № 195 от 08.06.2009 включённый в **"список грамматик, словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации"**.

Вот что в нём сейчас (6-е изд., 2016):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему у авторов словаря ***не хоженный*** названо причастием, от какого глагола и когда образовано это причастие?..  На эти вопросы ответить пока не берусь. Утверждать могу лишь одно: пока в этом, одном из наиболее авторитетных нормативных орфографических словарей русского языка присутствует такое написание, оно вправе быть использовано в любых текстах.

Comment: Slava, представьте, что  перед нами два словаря с разными решениями, и мы не знаем, какой из них авторитетнее (на них же не пишут: самый правильный орфографический словарь). Что делать? Попробуем обратиться к здравому смыслу. Вот мы пришли в магазин и видим: стоят диваны (не кровати!), но сказано, что они трансформируются в кровать, это их дополнительная функция. Тогда диван - это главное слово (м.р.), а кровать приложение, то есть словосочетание или составное наименование, в котором должны склоняться оба слова: новый диван-кровать - нового дивана-кровати.

Comment: Если не будем склонять первое слово, то получится сложное слово ж.р.: в продаже новая диван кровать - новой диван-кровати, а перед нами диван, а не кровать!